# Google Chrome has now removed the #https-upgrades flag; how do you prevent HTTP to HTTPS upgrades?

Tags: google-chrome

I've been using Google Chrome for a while, but just a couple of days ago the **HTTPS Upgrades** dropdown menu disappeared from `chrome://flags/httpsUpgrades`, and I couldn't find an alternative way to disable upgrades.

I'm typing from Google Chrome v. 123.0.6312.59 (64-bit).

Comment: What is the point of preventing upgrades?

Comment: @John: I can't view an old website anymore because it downloaded stylesheets and scripts from an http origin which is now auto-upgraded to https, causing it to fail.

Comment: I cannot assist.  HTTPS has been around and in use for a very long tme.

Comment: @John: I know. However the aforementioned site was created through a template and the management system doesn't allow to customize the protocol of the links (adds http:// automatically). The flag was there and working until like two or three days ago.

Comment: @Blindspots: Appreciated the efforts, but I'm not trying to prevent Google Chrome software updates, I'm trying to prevent Chrome from turning http:// requests to https:// requests automatically.

Comment: If you're willing to try other browsers, try the Brave browser, I believe it has an option to not allow HTTP to HTTPS upgrades/conversion.

Comment: @galacticninja: It works just fine in Firefox, I was just wondering if there's any way to view it in Chrome since it's my default browser.